# No Details in CreateOSD response

Tags: onvif

I'm trying to create new OSD configuration and my **request** looks like this(I omitted envelope and header because I have handled other methods, so it works for sure):

```
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CreateOSD xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl">
    <OSD token="osdtoken0"/>
  </CreateOSD>
</s:Body>
```

**Response from this request:** as you can see, I've got detail, which doesn't say much.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
  <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
      <SOAP-ENV:Code>
        <SOAP-ENV:Value>SOAP-ENV:Sender</SOAP-ENV:Value>
      </SOAP-ENV:Code>
      <SOAP-ENV:Reason>
        <SOAP-ENV:Text xml:lang="en">error</SOAP-ENV:Text>
      </SOAP-ENV:Reason>
      <SOAP-ENV:Detail>
        <error>CreateOSD error</error>
      </SOAP-ENV:Detail>
    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I also know my device support OSD because I can get current OSD's configurations:

```
<trt:GetOSDsResponse>
  <trt:OSDs token="osdtoken0">
    <tt:VideoSourceConfigurationToken>VIDEO_CH0</tt:VideoSourceConfigurationToken>
    <tt:Type>Text</tt:Type>
    <tt:Position>
      <tt:Type>Custom</tt:Type>
      <tt:Pos y="-1" x="-1"/>
    </tt:Position>
    <tt:TextString>
      <tt:Type>DateAndTime</tt:Type>
      <tt:DateFormat>yyyy-MM-dd</tt:DateFormat>
      <tt:TimeFormat>HH:mm:ss</tt:TimeFormat>
      <tt:FontSize>6</tt:FontSize>
      <tt:FontColor Transparent="0">
        <tt:Color Colorspace="" Z="0" Y="0" X="0"/>
      </tt:FontColor>
      <tt:BackgroundColor Transparent="0">
        <tt:Color Colorspace="" Z="0" Y="0" X="0"/>
      </tt:BackgroundColor>
    </tt:TextString>
  </trt:OSDs>
</trt:GetOSDsResponse>
```

I've also tried to add these signs like `<trt:>` to my request but in that case, I've got structure error response.

So, accordingly to [onvif media documentation](http://accordingly%20to%20https://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl/media.wsdl) - How to correctly structure CreateOSD request? Any help would be highly aprreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responses are never that great and usually quite generalized (no details).
You can try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:chan="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/02/duplex"
  xmlns:wsa5="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
  xmlns:c14n="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"
  xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
  xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
  xmlns:wsc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc"
  xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
  xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
  xmlns:xmime="http://tempuri.org/xmime.xsd"
  xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"
  xmlns:tt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema"
  xmlns:wsnt="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2"
  xmlns:wsrfbf="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2"
  xmlns:wstop="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1"
  xmlns:tds="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl"
  xmlns:tptz="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/ptz/wsdl"
  xmlns:trt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl">
 <SOAP-ENV:Header>
 </SOAP-ENV:Header>
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
   <trt:CreateOSD>
    <trt:OSD token="">
     <tt:VideoSourceConfigurationToken></tt:VideoSourceConfigurationToken>
     <tt:Type>Text</tt:Type>
     <tt:Position>
      <tt:Type></tt:Type>
      <tt:Pos x="0.0" y="0.0">
      </tt:Pos>
      <tt:Extension>
      </tt:Extension>
     </tt:Position>
     <tt:TextString>
      <tt:Type></tt:Type>
      <tt:DateFormat></tt:DateFormat>
      <tt:TimeFormat></tt:TimeFormat>
      <tt:FontSize>0</tt:FontSize>
      <tt:FontColor Transparent="0">
       <tt:Color X="0.0" Y="0.0" Z="0.0" Colorspace="">
       </tt:Color>
      </tt:FontColor>
      <tt:BackgroundColor Transparent="0">
       <tt:Color X="0.0" Y="0.0" Z="0.0" Colorspace="">
       </tt:Color>
      </tt:BackgroundColor>
      <tt:PlainText></tt:PlainText>
      <tt:Extension>
      </tt:Extension>
     </tt:TextString>
     <tt:Image>
      <tt:ImgPath></tt:ImgPath>
      <tt:Extension>
      </tt:Extension>
     </tt:Image>
     <tt:Extension>
     </tt:Extension>
    </trt:OSD>
   </trt:CreateOSD>

 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: I've got 'Well-formedness violation' using this structure.

Comment: What ONVIF camera are you testing against?

Comment: I've got "CreateOSD error" for "Infinova" and "Validation constraint violation: occurrence violation in element 'OSD'" message for Samsung

Comment: Sorry. I haven't worked with either of those. I have found, by experience, that sometimes the manufacturer just doesn't follow the spec properly, or in the case of Hikvision, I have found spelling mistakes against the ONVIF spec.
For example, in **profile.PTZConfiguration.$**, Hikvision did this: **DefaultAbsolutePantTiltPositionSpace** (notice the **Pant**?). Sometimes you have to be super observant in the responses and verify everything is spelled correctly against the spec, otherwise in your code you have to use "if/else" conditionals. Good luck!

Comment: By the way, I found the Hikvision spelling error by using their own ONVIF software and using Wireshark to see the response.

Comment: Actually, looking at your request.

It appears you are using an existing token **osdtoken0** to create a new OSD. That would be an error. Try using a token that doesn't exist, like **osdtoken1**. The response will return that token on success.

Comment: Unfortunately, It hasn't helped. Thank you for your effort though.